# To keep MySql and ES in sync, is Logstash the correct approach?

Tags: python, mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I used Logstash( a product of elastic.co ) to keep details in Mysql and ES in sync. Logstash periodically updates the changes in Mysql db to ES. Actually, Logstash is doing a pretty job. 
But,
1) Is it a reliable one ?
2) is it the correct approach ?
3) shall i continue using it ?

please give me more suggestion.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions are too broad to be answered since it's primarily opinion-based ones (1 & 3). But to answer the second one, yes it's the correct approach if you're dealing with `MySQL` and `ES` since `logstash` makes sure to keep your ES indice in sync with your data tables.

For 1 & 3, yes it's been proven that it's reliable and been used by [industries](https://www.elastic.co/use-cases) which are prominent. You might have to dig in deep if you're willing to do a comparison, though. But I would say it all depends on your own requirements and feasibilities if you're to go for a **yes/no**! Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!